# Trying to use arrays while a int statement in a while loop

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

I need the values 2,4,8,10,15,20 when I insert it but any other number I don't. This is what I came up with but it doesn't work.

```
int [] VALID_FUEL_TANKS = {2,4,8,10,15,20};
        int aNbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of Tanks"));
        while(aNbrTanks <= VALID_FUEL_TANKS){
            aNbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("valid number of Tanks"));
        }
```

I got the between certain number right but I'm trying to use arrays with JOption.

```
int aNbrVehicles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of Vehicles"));
        while(aNbrVehicles < 1  || aNbrVehicles > 10 ){
            aNbrVehicles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("valid number of Vehicles"));
        }
        int [] VALID_FUEL_TANKS = {2,4,8,10,15,20};
        int aNbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of Tanks"));
        while(aNbrTanks <= VALID_FUEL_TANKS){
            aNbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("valid number of Tanks"));
        }
```

Comment: Does that mean you want to accept input values only if they are contained in `VALID_FUEL_TANKS`?

Comment: while(aNbrTanks <= VALID_FUEL_TANKS){ what exactly do you think this does?